# KO Grid Display Isseues, On resize Gird shows one row. Images also included

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, hottowel, kogrid

Using the following.

1) Visual Studio 2012.
2) Hot towel template.
3) downloaded ko grid and and its css.

home.html

```
<section id="alerts-view" class="view">
 <header>
        <a class="btn btn-info btn-force-refresh pull-right" 
            data-bind="click: refresh" href="#"><i class="icon-refresh"></i> Refresh</a>
        <h3 class="page-title" data-bind="text: title"></h3>
        <div class="article-counter">
            <address data-bind="text: alerts().length"></address>
            <address>found</address>
        </div>
    </header>
    <div  data-bind="koGrid: gridOptions"></div>
  </section>
```

home.js

```
define(['services/datacontext', 'durandal/plugins/router'],
    function (datacontext, router) {

        var alerts = ko.observableArray();
        isAttachedToView = ko.observable(false);

        var activate = function (routeData) {
            if (routeData.id == undefined)
                return datacontext.getAlerts(alerts);
        };

        var deactivate = function () {
            isAttachedToView(false);
            alerts([]);
        };

        var refresh = function () {
            return datacontext.getAlerts(alerts);
        };


       var vm = {
            activate: activate,
            deactivate: deactivate,
            refresh: refresh,
            alerts: alerts,
            gridOptions: {
                            data: alerts,
                            canSelectRows: true,
                            enableColumnResize: true,
                            footerVisible: true,
                            displaySelectionCheckbox: true,
                            enableSorting: ko.observable(true),
                            columnDefs: [
                                            { field: 'efficency', displayName: 'Green or C02 Bus' } ......................

                                        ]

                           },
            isAttachedToView: isAttachedToView,
            title: 'Current Alerts'
        };
       return vm;


       function viewAttached() {
           isAttachedToView(true);
           return true;
       }
    });
```

Bundle config.

```
bundles.Add(
new StyleBundle("~/Content/css")

//.Include("~/Content/ie10mobile.css")
//.Include("~/Content/bootstrap.css")
//.Include("~/Content/bootstrap-responsive.css")
//.Include("~/Content/font-awesome.css")
//.Include("~/Content/durandal.css")
.Include("~/Content/toastr.css")
//  .Include("~/Content/app.css")
.Include("~/Content/KoGrid.css")
//  .Include("~/Content/jquery-ui-1.9.1.custom.css")

);
```

[image: first Picure]

Second Picture
[image: second picture only one row.]
I have no idea on what's going wrong or what i am doing wrong here, but  looks like the following 2 pictures.

first dont see any grid.
Resize the window you see the grid but only one row.
try and group on the G green buss then when you want to make the col bigger the second col starts to shift rather than the fist one.

is there some thing which works or example which works with Hottowel template and kogrid which i can download and use?

Looks like a schoolboy error, but difficult to find and reason.

Comment: Any javascript error on loading? Looks like something is not loaded properly.

Comment: no 404's int the traffic, so assume that there are no javascript errors. also cheked the console log no error's there as well.

Answer (score 2):

I'm faced with that problem as well.
Strangely, it seems viewport div (the one generated by kogrid with a classname of `kgViewport`) is set to a fixed height of 20 px.

As a workaround, I had jQuery fix that for me (last line in my viewmodel):

```
$("div.kgViewport").css("height", "inherit");
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution to the issue in your second picture is setting a height to the div. This should work:

```
<div style="border: 2px solid gray; height: 500px;" data-bind="koGrid: gridOptions"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks Sanjeev, that did not work either, only on resize it worked. but there was no data shown. Crazy issues.

Comment: What happens if you try to put the koGrid div outside of the <section> tag all by itself?

Comment: Still the same, Strange. it works for all but not for this one. Lots of ko grid issues on the Durandal google groups. i hope some will help with an answer.

Answer (score 0):

You should set explicit width and height on the element you bind to.

```
<div class="myGrid" data-bind="koGrid: gridOptions"></div>
```

and then in your stylesheet

```
.myGrid {
    width: 700px;
    height: 300px;
}
```