# KO Grid Scrollbars not visible & Display issues

Tags: height, width, scrollbar, kogrid

I am having two problems with KOgrid.

1) I could not get scroll bars in the kogrid .It is very difficult to do  data entry without scroll bars.

2) I also could not get kogrid to working wihout specifying hard coded height and width.In my application I can not have a fixed height and width.
 Did anybody else had the same issue ?

I tried  a workaround suggestion from this thread ( using  jQuery fix as last line in my viewmodel). 
[KO Grid Display Isseues, On resize Gird shows one row. Images also included](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17755201/ko-grid-display-isseues-on-resize-gird-shows-one-row-images-also-included)

that just increased that size of the grid but it did not display any data . However, when I resize the page data shows up.

Below are my HTML and kogrid options ( I tried with and without paging options, Ideally I do not want to use paging )

```
 <div data-bind="koGrid: gridOptions" 
    style="height: 800px; background-color: none;width: 1850px;">
  </div>


  self.gridOptions = {
        data: self.mydatarray,
        footerVisible: true,
        displaySelectionCheckbox: true,
        afterSelectionChange: self.RowSelectionChange,
        rowHeight: 50,
        selectWithCheckboxOnly: true,
        enableSorting: false,
        multiSelect: true,
        selectedItems: self.SelectedRows,
        enableColumnResize: true,
        showFilter: false,
        canSelectRows: true,
        enablePaging: true,
        pagingOptions: {
            currentPage: ko.observable(1), 
            pageSize: ko.observable(3),
            pageSizes: ko.observableArray([3, 6, 9])

        },
        rowTemplate: errrowtmpl,
        columnDefs: [
            { field: 'Customer', displayName: 'Customer', cellTemplate: Customersddedittmpl, headerCellTemplate: headercelltmpl },
              ...
      ...

            { field: 'GenNotes', displayName: 'GenNotes', cellTemplate: simpleedittmpl, headerCellTemplate: headercelltmpl }
        ]

    }
```

Please let me know if you need any more information

Thanks

Kenner Dev

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a solution to the problems I am facing.

1) I used Jquery to add scroll bar. I added code line below as last line of my data loading function. I am not sure id this breaks any other KOGrid functionality.In my application I did some basic testing and it seems to be working  fine.

```
    $("div.kgViewport").css("overflow", "scroll");
```

2) I still dont know how to solve this problem 100%. It still does not work unless fixed width and height are mentioned in style. In my app I used vw and vh as opposed fixed width and height to solve the problem of making it work on all screen sizes.

```
  <div data-bind="koGrid: gridOptions" 
    style="height: 73vh;overflow:scroll;width: 96vw;"></div>
```